# Code::Blocks reports another instance running, even when there isn't one

Tags: codeblocks

When I try running *Code::Blocks*, I get the following error message:

> Another program instance is already running.
>   Code::Blocks is currently configured to only allow one running instance.
>
> You can access this Setting under the menu item 'Environment'.

I had a similar problem before with e.g. Google Chrome when I didn't shut it down correctly, but for Chrome, I managed to locate the lock file, delete it, and it solves the problem.

For *Code::Blocks*, I looked around and tried several proposed solutions, but none of them worked:

- look for the process (`ps -A | grep 'codeblocks'`) and kill the process

  I found a stray process this way, but killing it did not help.
- allow multiple instances *Setting* under *'Environment'* menu

  I can not run any instance in the first place, so can not access the menu.

  I tried running *Code::Blocks* from terminal with `codeblocks --multiple-instances` but that parameter must have been abandoned some time ago, as it is no longer recognized.
- I looked all over for some kind of a lock file, to try and delete it

  Unfortunately, I didn't find anything that looked to me distinctly like the lock file :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uh, sorry everybody, looks like I have this annoying habit of finding a solution within minutes of complaining about the problem, instead in my "look for solution" phase.

I found the lock file to delete and fix the problem: deleting `/tmp/Code::Blocks-username` fixes the problem.

Some further solutions are outlined [in the *Code::Blocks* official forums](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=8529.0), including how to change the settings from "allow single instance" to "allow multiple instance" without actually running *Code::Blocks*.

Answer (score -2):

Follow the following steps

1. Go to `Settings` -> `Environment` -> `General settings`
2. Uncheck `Allow only one running instance ...`
3. Check `Use an already running instance ...`
4. Check `Bring it on top afterwards`

Comment: This wouldn't work since I can't even start `Code::Blocks` when this happens